# Summation bug in 11.2

Tags: summation

If I sum all the positive-numbered Fourier coefficients of $\cos(x)$, I get the correct answer. If I sum the negative-numbered ones, I get a wrong answer. Splitting the sum into two parts somehow fixes the issue.

```
Sum[FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
Sum[FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, -k], {k, 1, Infinity}]
Sum[FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, -k], {k, 1, 2}] +  Sum[FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, -k], {k, 3, Infinity}]

Out:
1/2
0
1/2
```

Comment: This is the wrong place to report bugs.  Please report bugs directly to Wolfram Research: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/.

Comment: @QuantumDot is correct that bugs should be reported directly to Wolfram, Inc.  Nonetheless, warning StackExchange uses about bugs is a useful service, and I thank you for doing so.  Be sure to attached the usual bug header to your question, along with the case number that Wolfram, Inc assigns to your report, in a day or so, after others have had a chance to comment on the problem you identified here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is not with `Sum`:

```
FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, -k]
(*  0  *)

FourierCoefficient[Cos[x], x, k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second code is also much faster.  It suggests to me that `FourierCoefficient` calls `Integrate` in the first case and uses a short-cut in the second.  In fact `Integrate` (from a [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) of `FourierCoefficient`) gives a result that is only generically correct:

```
Integrate[E^(I k x) Cos[x], {x, -π, π}, 
 Assumptions -> k ∈ Integers, GenerateConditions -> False]
(* -((2 k Sin[k π])/(-1 + k^2))  *)
```

Comment: Interesting, so it's a consequence of the fact that the symbolic value of that integral formally breaks down at $k=\pm 1$? I wonder how `FourierCoefficient` normally avoids this problem.

Comment: @level1807 It seems for a simple symbol `k` as opposed to an expression `-k`, that instead of integration, `Cos[x]` is expanded as a series in `q = Exp[I x]` and `SeriesCoefficient` is used to get the general series coefficient of order `k`.  `SeriesCoefficient` does a better job than `Integrate` in this case.

Answer (score 8):

This is not an answer as why it happens. But the change happened after version 7.

I went back to verion 7 to be able to obtain different result. I tried versions 11, 10, 9, and 8 and they all gave same result as above. But in version 7:

[image]

Comment: That's quite strange...